# JPA2 PersistentObjectException "Detached entity passed to persist" but which one?

Tags: jpa-2.0

I'm having problems with a rather complex piece of code: it throws a PersistentObjectException: Detached entity passed to persist. I'm not going to ask you why, the code is far too complex to post here (multiple joined inheritance classes, OneToMany, ManyToOne, WhateverToWhatever, stuff to avoid 63 tables mysql limit in joins and so on...).

I need only to know if there is a way, during debug, using the variables inspector, to reach the reference to the detached object that caused the exception.

I already know its class, the exception tells it, but I believe I'm not persisting any object of that class (which is abstract by the way...). I'm obviously wrong here, and being able to inspect that object while the program is paused on a breakpoint would be very helpful.

My provider is Hibernate-entitymanager 4.1.9.Final.

Btw, I'm not even calling persist(), I'm calling only merge().

EDIT: I've finally managed to find the detached entity, it took nearly 10 hours of debugging. I guess it could be faster if there were a way to reach the entity through the exception and (more importantly) if the exception message was more precise: the entity class wasn't the one specified, which is abstract, but a subclass of that (obviously I would say, but I have nearly 20 subclasses of that abstract class and guessing the right one was not trivial).